# How was the raspi-config GUI made?

Tags: software-development, software-recommendation, raspi-config

The `raspi-config` UI looks like this:

[image: raspi-config UI]

How was this program made? Could I, for instance, write a program with graphical elements like this that runs in the shell? Is there a library that does something similar?

Comment: It looks like it is using the newt library http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_(programming_library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/asb/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config) you will see it is a bash script that uses `whiptail` to create the menus.

whiptail is part of the [newt library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_%28programming_library%29)

Comment: You don't see these too often, but I think using a TUI is an exceptionally good way for making a somewhat visual application on a low-powered device (or in a shell environment). Thanks!